# Como se puede hacer esta consulta SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, report, querybuilder

Buenas me gustaría saber como podría hacer esta consulta SQL porque me tiene dando muchas vueltas este ejercicio quisiera saber vuestra opinión de como se podría ejecutar esta consulta a una base de datos SQL server 2017 por medio del programa Report Builder , tengo esta duda porque no se ni por donde tomar este ejercicio, muchas gracias.

Esta fue la consulta que use:

```
SELECT factura.Fecha ,factura.Numero ,factura.TotalFactura 
FROM factura;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bueno la consulta es basica, que fue lo que intentaste?

Comment: @gbianchi esto fue lo que intente   --- SELECT
  factura.Fecha
  ,factura.Numero
  ,factura.TotalFactura
FROM
  factura

Comment: eso deberia ir en la pregunta.. para lo que te piden tenes que usar funciones de agregacion (y un group by)

Comment: Creería que es necesario ver la estructura de la base de datos para saber que query extrae bien los datos. Las imágenes segunda y tercera están de más, no agregan información relevante a la pregunta.

Comment: @gbianchi me podrías dar un ejemplo si no fuera mucha molestia para poder ubicarme muchas gracias.

Comment: @Alfredo Maussa gracias hay coloque la estructura y edite la publicación

Comment: no. investiga sobre group by.. este es un ejercicio que se usa para justamente que aprendas group by....

Comment: @gbianchi muchas gracias empezare a desarrollarlo como me indicaste , muchas gracias por el apoyo muchas bendiciones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un poco más de contexto ayudaría mucho, como cuál es el servidor en el que tienes tu base de datos.

De todos modos, esto puede ayudarte como punto de partida:

```
SELECT
EXTRACT(month from factura.Fecha) as Mes,
COUNT(factura.Numero) as 'Cantidad de Facturas',
SUM(factura.TotalFactura) as Monto
FROM factura
GROUP BY EXTRACT(month from factura.Fecha)
```